# Techniques to manage updates to a postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

The goal is to build a concise SQL script to alter/update tables since changes have been made to the schema between any two points in time.

For example, I develop on one machine and on Day "A" I used the dump & restore utilities to install a database on a production machine.  Then on Day "B" after making some changes on my development machine and testing them, I need to get those changes to my schema onto my production server.

Short of writing every single command I make to my schema (some of which may be experimental and undone), what is a good way to manage upgrading a schema from point A to point B (or point B to point F for that matter)?

**Update:**

It seems that diff-like concepts for databases are very much frowned upon with good reason.  So this leaves me with new questions.

1. What is a simple method to distinctly manage your experimental changes from your production-worthy changes?  Just keep restoring your dev database to a last known good state when you do something unfavorable?
2. Can postgresql be configured to log all of your actions in a way that can be pulled out as used as an update script?  The reason I ask is that I enjoy working with PgAdminIII, and I would rather use that to work than to write update scripts for building or experimenting.

Answer (score 3):

> *Short of writing every single command I make to my schema*

If you want to do it in a controlled and "professional" way, there is no way around that. You should consider using a schema management tool to help you organize and run those migration scripts:

- [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)
- [Flyway](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/)

Our experience with Liquibase is very good. We use it for migrations on Oracle, DB2 and PostgreSQL.

For a Postgres specific solution you might want to have a look at [Sqitch](https://github.com/theory/sqitch)

Comment: And forget about any magical tools which just compare two database schemas and generate DDL script for getting from point A to point D. This is not code, this is database with real data, this is very important to get from point A to point D through points B and C.

Comment: @SzymonGuz: good point. Trying to diff (a possibly messy) development (or test) database against a "clean" production database is going to fail at some point.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. These are good points, and so I revised my question.